# Is Terraform possible to use for local development?

Tags: terraform

I would like to use Terraform for the infrastructure of my project and am starting to look into it for local development. I am brand new to it so apologies if this is a basic thing to know. So far from my research it appears like it is more useful / helpful when deploying it to a Cloud provider. Is it possible to use it for local development such as connecting to local Docker containers or am I better off waiting and using it when I start to set it up in the Cloud?

Comment: Many local developments have the terrain (re)-formed prior to building commencing.

Comment: interesting thread: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/configure-both-local-development-and-production-environments-with-terraform/25061/5

Comment: You can use Terraform for local development, there are providers for that as well, one example being Docker.

Comment: you could use null_resources and local-exec to run ad-hoc scripts to set up your local infrastructure too.